# What's wrong with this Java Coded if STatement?

Tags: java

I am not a professional programer. I am still learning, so my code is a little basic right now.

```
Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String UserChoose = UserInput.next();
if (UserChoose=="Quit"){
```

I have deduced that there is something missing in the if statement, but I cannot figure out what. Can someone please tell me what I am missing? I have been searching online for an hour with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (UserChoose.equals("Quit")){
```

In java, the default == operator compare if they both are the same object, even if the content is the same, if the object reference is not the same, it isn't `==`.

[See this link for more complete explanation:  http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/](http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/)

Comment: small `e` for `equals`

Answer (score 0):

To compare objects in java use .equals() method instead of "==" operator

Replace  `if (UserChoose=="Quit"){` with    `if (UserChoose.equals("Quit")){`

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake, use UserChoose.equals("Quit") to compare strings.
Since String is an object, using == will likely compare the memory location the 2 strings or something that would always result with false.